# If the support of a distribution has lebesgue measure zero, then the distribution is singular.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Googling the definition of a "singular distribution" I've come across both this definition, the derivative being zero almost everywhere when the distribution is absolutely continuous, and the definition regarding density.

I understand the definition of density going to the cdf being derivative 0 a.e.

What I don't see is how if the support is lebesgue measure 0 that it also implies it is singular.

Comment: This is  a theorem on differentiation of measures. See Theorem 13 in the chapter on Differentiation in Rudin's RCA.